# Use of Google Directions Service in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps api v3..
According to This [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Directions) I can able to get the Path between any 2 points as in the [Example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/directions-simple).

Not I want to get the Same using VB.Net.. I want to get the same result in the server side processing (Means want to get the Path[lat lon pair]).

I have tried with the code

```
  Dim lat As Double = 17.38489
        Dim lon As Double = 78.486939

        Dim lat2 As Double = 20.296095
        Dim lon2 As Double = 85.82459

        'For counter As Integer = 0 To 1
        Try

            Dim myURL As String = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" & lat.ToString("0.000000") & "," & lon.ToString("0.000000") & "&destination=" & lat2.ToString("0.000000") & "," & lon2.ToString("0.000000") & "&sensor=false"
            Dim myRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(myURL)

            myRequest.Method = "GET"

            ' Add request headers
            myRequest.KeepAlive = True
            myRequest.Accept = "*/*"
            myRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0;)"
            myRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-us")
            myRequest.Referer = "http://www.google.com/mapmaker?ll=16.303005,81.05464&spn=0.021583,0.040684&z=15"
            myRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-sg")
            'myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

            Dim c As Char = "c"

            Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

            ' Send the request and get the response
            Dim myResponse As HttpWebResponse = myRequest.GetResponse

            Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream())
            sb.Append(reader.ReadToEnd())
            reader.Close()
            myResponse.Close()

            Dim s As String = sb.ToString()

            Dim ds As String = s
            Response.Write(s)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

Can any one Help me out..

Comment: Can you post an example of the response you receive? Or any error messages that you are encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure doing this server-side is against the TOS? Plus there are limits to how many requests can be made from an IP address. What happens if you go over that limit? You need to check for error messages from Google and handle them gracefully. If you're paying for the service then there will probably be less restrictions.